# How do i change the default drag and drop cursor?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cursor

I use a simple JavaScript drag and drop system.
However I want to change the default drag and drop move cursor
[image]

to another cursor like the pointer for example:

[image]

How can I change the looks of my drag and drop cursor? I tried setting the cursor css on `body:hover` with no effect and some other things.
There must be a relatively simple solution right? What am I missing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/dropEffect

Comment: @Teemu yea i've read the documentation thanks ... The documentation only shows how to set the drop effect but not how to change the drop icon